# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unable to connect to the remote server, when accessing a blob storage from octopus

Tags: azure, storage, octopus-deploy, blobstorage, octopus

When I keep creating different storage names(random names) and using the blob from octopus it is reassigned/reusing some IP address for each storage account and throwing the connection is actively refused.

for every run, I delete the storage account and recreate it. Why same IP address is getting assigned to the storage.

below are the IP Addresses I am getting

```
52.179.144.72:443
52.184.168.104:443
52.179.144.72:443
52.184.168.104:443
52.226.8.136:443
52.179.144.72:443
52.226.8.136:443
52.226.8.136:443
```

Error:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unable to connect to
>   the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to
>   the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 52.184.168.104:443

I am getting access isssue with only with ip address starting with 52.X.X.X
this is getting resolved to blob.bz6prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage is a multi-tenant Storage-as-a-Service. The IP address (or addresses) is to the service itself, not to your specific namespace. There's no specific deployment or related IP address created for you; just a namespace. You should only be accessing your storage account via its name (e.g. `mystoragename.blob.core.windows.net`).